# C++ advices on seperating sourcecode into multiple header and cpp

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

since I want to build now bigger Projects in C++ I thought about dividing my code into header/cpp files.
But I have problems compiling, because my wrong use of multiple `#include` .

main.cpp

```
#include"device.h"
#include"checksum.h"
int main()
```

device.h

```
#pragma once
#include "structures.h"

void getDevice(); /* pcpa_if_t* dev */
void openDevice();/* pcap_t* handle */
void applyFilter(const char* filter_exp); /* compiles and applies */
```

device.cpp

```
#include "device.h"

pcap_if_t* alldevs;
pcap_if_t* dev;
pcap_t* handle;
struct bpf_program fp;
bpf_u_int32 mask;
bpf_u_int32 net;
char filter_exp[] = "ip";
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

void getDevice() { ...
```

structures.h

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<pcap.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#define SNAP_LEN 1518 ...
```

checksum.cpp

```
#include "checksum.h"
```

checksum.h

```
 #pragma once
    #include "structures.h"
```

This code does not compile, the problem is checksum.h cpp, I don't know why.
Should I feel free to reuse library includes when necessary, or do I need to change the cern-structure for more efficiency?
Should the includes go into the header or cpp file, does it matter?
Is it good practise to use pragma once on all header?
On simple examples Im fine, but I get really fast troubles when working with more headers and cpp files.

[Compiler-Error: Functions already defined.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkblG.png)

Comment: What compiler (with version) you using? MSVC?

Comment: Microsoft C++ compiler, using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Well since i cant read German i can only tell that your compiler is indeed warning you about multiple defintions in checksum. Try adding a `pragma once` to checksum.h (before the include) as its in both main.cpp and checksum.cpp

Comment: This requires a [mre].

Comment: The most widely used method to provoke a "already defined" error is to define them in a header (.h, .hpp) or to include a code file (.cpp). An MRE would allow to check that. Without you need to do it yourself.